# Empty array on React state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I'm using a backend on ruby-on-rails, when my API calls for 'transactions' it returns a JSON, which works fine when tested via insomnia, but my mapping does not work. Here's my react page:

```
interface Transaction {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  transaction_type: string;
  description: string;
  value: number;
}

const Index: React.FC = () => {
  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState<Transaction[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    api.get('transactions').then((response) => {
      setTransactions(response.data);
      // console.log(response.data, transactions)
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Transactions</h1>
      {transactions.map((transaction) => {
        <div>{transaction.title}</div>;
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

On the backend side its simply returns a JSON with my database result:

```
#transactions_controller.rb
def index
  render json: @transactions = Transaction.all
end
```

[image: Insomnia result]

My routes are pointing to path: **'/api/'**.

When the **console.log** shows the response.data it is correct, but when showing the transactions state its empty.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: The map function is not returning anything. Update the map to `{transactions.map(transaction => (<div>{transaction.title}</div>))}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the return in the map.

```
{transactions.map(transaction => {
    return (<div>{transaction.title}</div>)
})}
```

Or you can remove the curly braces `{` from you map and it will return imlicitly.

```
{transactions.map(transaction => <div>{transaction.title}</div> )}
```

Comment: Thanks man, can't believe that I've not noticed that LOL

Answer (score -1):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
> batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
> right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

That's why your console.log doesn't work, and as pointed in a previous answer you're missing the return in the map that's why you are probably not seeing results in the screen

Answer (score -2):

That is because ajax calls are asynchronous, so by the time the component accesses the transactions, it will still be an empty array, best way will be to check if the transactions have been loaded before

using the snippet below solves the issue

```js
interface Transaction {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  transaction_type: string;
  description: string;
  value: number;
}

const Index : React.FC = () => {
const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState<Transaction[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  api.get('transactions').then(response => {
    setTransactions(response.data);
    // console.log(response.data, transactions)
  });   
}, []);

return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Transactions</h1>
      {transactions.length && transactions.map(transaction =>
        <div>{transaction.title}</div>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Index
```

NB: transactions.length act as a boolean flag which returns false if it is 0

Comment: In this case it is not necessary to check `transactions.length` because `transactions` are initialized as an (empty) array so it won't cause an error by trying to map over undefined, and whenever the state of `transactions` updates it will re-render and map again over the current array in `transactions`